# Cite report without author

Tags: bibtex

I would like to cite a report published by an institution. They don't publish the names of the authors. Right now I'm using

```
@TechReport{bissurvey,
    title = {Triennial Central Bank Survey of foreign exchange and derivatives market activity in 2013},
    year = {2013},
    month ={sep},
    editor = {Bank for International Settlements}, 
}
```

This produces a citation of the type (International Settlements", 2013). I'm not sure what the proper entry type for a publication like this is (I just assumed TechReport).

What would the proper way of doing this in BibTeX be? I'd like for the "Bank of" part not to be cut off.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you can use the name of the institution as the author?  After all, it IS the author

Comment: This gives me the same citation, i. e. the "Bank of" part is cut off.

Comment: use `author={{Bank for International Settlements}}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, I see no reason why you shouldn't use the Institution as author of the Report.  As such, the `bib` entry should look something like this:

```
@TechReport{bissurvey,
    title = {Triennial Central Bank Survey of foreign exchange and derivatives market activity in 2013},
    year = {2013},
    month ={sep},
    author ={{Bank of International Settlements}},
    editor = {Bank for International Settlements Editorial Group}, 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the second pair of curly brackets solved my problem of an Institution that contains an "and" (like in "Bank for International Settlements and Fun Group") and was interpreted as two authors.

Comment: Isn't there already an "institution" field for TechReports?

Comment: And annoyingly you get a warning if you don't supply both author and institution.