# How to cite books published by organizations using natbib

Tags: natbib

What would be the best way to cite a material published from an organization? I tried using misc, but the .bst file I am using does not accept this, the item disappears from the reference list.

If I use the @article format, I don't get the citation correctly. For instance, if the org name is The World Bank, then using natbib would detect the last word as last name and do:

> Bank, The World (2006) Report on health facilities

How can I get instead,

> The World Bank (2006) Report on health facilities

I am using this .bst file:  https://github.com/svmiller/jpr-bst-file/blob/master/jpr.bst

Comment: The issue of which entry type -- `@article`, `@book`, `@misc`, etc -- is appropriate for a given publication is entirely separate from the issue of how the name of a "corporate" author, e.g., "The World Bank", should be entered. For corporate authors, which (obviously) lack first names and surnames, the way to go is to encase the entire author field in an additional pair of curly braces. E.g., `author = {{The World Bank}}`. With this device, BibTeX is led to believe that the author's name consists of just one part, which must be the "surname" -- which doesn't get split or rearranged.

Comment: @Mico I also found that just now, here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181242/cite-report-without-author Thank you!!!

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864 (and my comments on corporate authors in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480431/35864). If an organisation can be said to have authoring role it is fine to put it into the `author` field, but extra braces are needed to avoid the effect you see. I just tested the linked style with a `@misc` entry and even though the comments only suggest that `@article`, `@book`, `@incollection` and `@unpublished` are supported, the code contains functions for `@misc` and it printed just fine for me.